# Component has updated but no visual change

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm pretty new to React and I'm pulling my hair out over this one:

**HTML**

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

**JS**

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { title: props.title };
  }

  render() {
    return ()<div>{this.state.title}</div>);
  }
}

class TestApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      children: [
        <Child title='a' />,
        <Child title='b' />
      ]};
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log('[componentDidUpdate]');
    console.log('prevChildren: ' + prevState.children.map(c => c.props.title).join(', '));
    console.log('children: ' + this.state.children.map(c => c.props.title).join(', '));
  }

  handleOnClick = () => {
    console.log('[handleOnClick]');

    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        children: [
          <Child title='c' />,
          <Child title='d' />
        ]
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log('[render]');

    return (
      <div>
        <div>TEST</div>
        {this.state.children}
        <button onClick={this.handleOnClick}>CHANGE</button>
      </div>
      )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TestApp />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/robloche/pen/xmGMBy

What's happening in the console when I click the button is:

```
[handleOnClick]
[render]
[componentDidUpdate]
prevChildren: a, b
children: c, d
```

which looks pretty good to me but somehow, `a` and `b` are still displayed instead of `c` and `d`...
What did I miss?

Comment: I dont think using child components in state is very good approach to build a component. try conditional rendering and keep you components clear off your state. Its not a recommended practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have an array of `Child` elements then React can't distinguish when they've actually been updated/replaced with new ones.

Add a unique `key` to each `Child` and it will work, e.g.

`<Child key='a' title='a'/>`,
`<Child key='b' title='b'/>`,
etc.

NB! When dealing with arrays of Components then the `key` property is mandatory and while it will help in this case as well, your current approach is not very optimal.

Instead of creating whole new Components on a state change you should instead store only their values (`title` in this case) and then have the `render()` method deal with it.

The following is pseudo-pseudo code as I only added the pertinent parts to show how it would work.

```
constructor() {
  this.state = {
    children: ['a', 'b']
  }
}

onClick() {
  this.setState({
    children: ['c', 'd']
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <>
      {this.state.children.map(title => <Child key={title} title={title}/>)}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. That was not exactly my issue here but that led me to the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use state in child component. you do not have any dependency of the child props, just use parent component's props and it should work fine.

Change:

```
return (<div>{this.state.title}</div>);
```

to

```
return (<div>{this.props.title}</div>);
```

The problem you are facing right now is that parent is changed to c,d and it has been passed as child too, but because react doesn't have any keys update or state updates it does not re-render the component. The best approach is to use the props passed from the parent and use them.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/dholakiyaankit/pen/LMVvVZ?editors=1011)

Comment: Thanks. It's working now but I don't get it... When I replace the content of `children` with 2 new `Child` components, I thought that 2 new instances of `Child` were created but I just did the test and the constructor is not called...

Comment: Constructor will not call because you already have initiated child component, the best approach is to use props only because you are already passing the values for it. do not use the constructor atall in child one when you don't have to apply the state.

Comment: @Justcode, your comment is not technically correct in this situation. The constructor **is** called and new `Child`ren are created and added to the state with the correct title, the problem is that the view is not re-rendered because React cannot differentiate the new `Child`ren from the old ones. Check the beginning part of my answer.

Comment: @rorschach To justify your concern, I have added the statement do not use constructor in your case, because of the state is useless to use when you already have parent passed props, however I totally agree that passing new instances will result in invoking the constructor and new instances too. But, not recommended approach.

Comment: @Justcode, I agree with your concern and it's something important to keep in mind in the future as we're dealing with stateless Components but your answer does not explain *why* the view does not re-render.

Comment: @rorschach view re-renders. But having react in middle it checks the component 
is updated or not, because he is using the old props react blocks the re-render.

Comment: @Justcode, I apologize for arguing, you're absolutely correct. I should've done a more comprehensive test before dismissing your answer.

Comment: @rorschach not to worry, its good to have a doubt clear, helps a lot in future.